# Diferença entre uma linguagem bloqueante e uma linguagem não bloqueante

Tags: desempenho, arquitetura-de-software

Na prática, qual a diferença entre uma linguagem bloqueante e uma não bloqueante?

Quais as diferenças que podemos observar tanto no front-end como no back-end?

Utilizando um exemplo, vamos imaginar um endpoint de uma API em que algo é escrito num banco de dados e é devolvido ao cliente uma resposta qualquer.

Se várias requisições são feitas ao mesmo tempo para esse endpoint, na prática como se comportaria um sistema com uma arquitetura bloqueante e outro não bloqueante?

Comment: É linguagem ou algoritmo? Nunca vi o termo ser usado para uma linguagem.

Comment: @bigown pensei que esse termo era usado como característica de uma linguagem. Seria interessante a resposta começar explicando que isso é um erro. Essa questão surgiu porque comecei a estudar NodeJS.

Answer (score 5):

## Explicação

Em um sistema bloqueante as requisições seriam enfileiradas e depois disso seriam processadas uma a uma, dessa forma não seria possível processar várias delas ao mesmo tempo. Ou seja o cliente que tem a requisição mais nova só terá sua requisição processada depois que as requisições mais velhas tiverem sido processadas por inteiro.

E nas não-bloqueantes teremos que a requisição do cliente mais novo poderá ser processada (ou pelo menos uma parte dela) antes que todas requisições que o servidor recebeu antes dela sejam processadas.

## Exemplo

Supondo que o exemplo é um sistema de PetShop, e que a requisição tem como finalidade adicionar um Animal que pertence a um Dono ao Banco de Dados e adicionar esse Dono caso não esteja no Banco de Dados.

#### Bloqueante

O Cliente que enviou a requisição mais antiga só terá o Animal e o Dono no Banco de Dados depois que todas as outras requisições já foram processadas. No pior caso teremos uma operação de I/O que demore horas, e assim o cliente mais novo não terá sua resposta a sua requisição tão cedo.

#### Não Bloqueante

O Cliente que enviou a requisição mais antiga poderá ter pelo menos o Animal registrado no Banco de Dados mesmo que ainda tenha requisições mais antigas sendo processadas. Nesse caso mesmo que o I/O demore o sistema ainda atenderá a outras requisições.